# Uncaught TypeError: "#text1".val is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have three html pages

**home_frame.html**

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/myscript.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="tab">
    <button  id="button1"          >Button 1</button>
    <button id="button2"   >Button 2</button>
</div>
<div id="bt_one_content" >
</div>
<div id="bt_two_content" >
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

**first.html**

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="text1" >
 <input type="button" id="bt_One" value="Say hello Button One">
</body>
</html>
```

**second.html**

```html
 <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
     <input type="text" id="text2" >
     <input type="button" id="bt_two" value="Say hello Button Two">
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am placing `first.html` and `second.html` in `home_frame.html` when corresponding button clicks  using jquery and codeigniter

**myscript.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function(event){

 $("#button1").click(function(event){
    loadFirstView();
 });
 $("#button2").click(function(event){
   loadSecondView();
 });
 $(document).on('click', '#bt_One', function(){
   var val = $("#text1").val();
 });
   $(document).on('click', '#bt_two', function(){
   var val = $("#text2").val();
 });

});
```

When try to get text from dynamically loaded text field i am getting error

```
Uncaught TypeError: "#text1".val is not a function
```

Comment: did you added  `myscript.js` in those two pages which button click not working?Also any error in console.? did you added jQuery library before your script file?

Comment: @AlivetoDie Not inclded in my child view,included jquery before script file

Comment: @RogerC I  am trying to implement card type layout